# RubyZip set file timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubyzip

I have been banging my head the whole day on this, maybe you can help?
I am zipping the file with RubyZip and I need to set the time of that file creation/update/modification to the certain time in time zone (which depends on the client time zone I have in the `@time_zone` variable).

I know it is most likely super incorrect, and I have taken that magic string `'UT\x5\0\x3\250$\r@Ux\0\0'` from the RubyZip tests file, and I have no idea what this is. LOL.
However - I have made it work now on my PC. It really zips the file and sets the correct timestamps for it according to the specified time zone.

BUT - it doesn't work on the app server, which as OS time zone is in UTC time zone. It generates some other time for files which doesn't match.

Here's how far I made it work:

```
def save_to_zip(file_path)
  Zip::OutputStream.open(file_path) do |out|
    @sheets.each do |csv|
      name = csv.name
      extra = time_for_zip
      out.put_next_entry("#{name}.#{@file_extension}", nil, extra)
      tmpfile = csv.tmpfile
      tmpfile.close
      source = File.open(tmpfile.path, 'r')
      source.each do |line|
        out.write(line)
      end
    end
  end
end

def time_for_zip
  return nil if @time_zone.blank?

  timestamp = Zip::ExtraField.new('UT\x5\0\x3\250$\r@Ux\0\0')
  localtime_str = Time.now.in_time_zone(@time_zone).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
  dos_time_in_store_tz = ::Zip::DOSTime.parse(localtime_str)

  timestamp['UniversalTime'].ctime = dos_time_in_store_tz
  timestamp['UniversalTime'].atime = dos_time_in_store_tz
  timestamp['UniversalTime'].mtime = dos_time_in_store_tz

  timestamp
end
```

Can you please tell me how can I set the file time correctly inside the zip file?

Really appreciated...

Maris

Answer (score 1):

Solved like this:

```
    def save_to_zip(file_path)
  Zip::OutputStream.open(file_path) do |out|
    @sheets.each do |csv|
      name = csv.name
      tmpfile = csv.tmpfile
      tmpfile.close
      source = File.open(tmpfile.path, 'r')
      zip_entry = Zip::Entry.new(out, "#{name}.#{@file_extension}", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, time_for_zip(source.ctime))
      out.put_next_entry(zip_entry)
      source.each do |line|
        out.write(line)
      end
    end
  end
end

def time_for_zip(file_time)
  return Zip::DOSTime.at(file_time) if @time_zone.blank?

  Zip::DOSTime.parse(file_time.utc.in_time_zone(@time_zone).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
end
```

Kudos to this thread: https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/pull/40